# How to use sample weighting in RandomizedSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am working with `scikit learn` library in `python` and I want to weight to each sample during the cross validation using RandomizedSearchCV. When I try this code:

```
search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator, param_distributions,
                                    n_iter=args.iterations,
                                    scoring=mae_scorer, n_jobs=8, refit=True,
                                    cv=KFold(X_train.shape[0], 10, shuffle=True,
                                             random_state=args.seed), verbose=1,
                                    random_state=args.seed,
                                    fit_params={'sample_weight': sample_weight})
```

The following error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

It is worth mentioning that `sample_weight` is a list of float numbers containing the weight of each class. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you generate this list? normally the scikit learn api generally accept numpy arrays as data so either pass this or create one from your list

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. I also have checked `numpy.asarray(sample_weight)` but I got this error:
`ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1118,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1118,1006)`
Do you have idea?

Comment: Try to isolate the problem, does it work without KFolds? Does it work with other training models? Check your types of the params you are passing, how do these compare with the online docs and code samples? Try all of this and see how you get on, difficult to say at the moment but my suggestions should help

Comment: @EdChum I think the problem is with `k-fold`. because when I changed the number of folds from 10 to 2 the number in error was changed from 1006 to 559. Do you know how should I fix that?

Comment: Not sure, hopefully one of the scikit-learn devs will see this and comment.

Comment: `sample_weight` should be an `(n_samples,)`-shaped array, not a list or `(n_samples,1)`-shaped array.

Answer (score 0):

```
search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator, param_distributions,
                                    n_iter=args.iterations,
                                    scoring=mae_scorer, n_jobs=8, refit=True,
                                    cv=KFold(X_train.shape[0], 10, shuffle=True,
                                             random_state=args.seed), verbose=1,
                                    random_state=args.seed
                             )

search.fit(X_train, np.ravel(y_train) 
              ,sample_weight=our_sample_weight
             )
```

Something like this works on my code.